# How to position links on a subdiv so that their underlining (when hovered over) sits on top of a margin line ruled under the entire parent div?

Tags: html, css

This is what I am trying to get:

[image]

So far I have got:

```css
#row1 {margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 5px; 
overflow: hidden;
border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;} 

#row1-col1 {width: 100px;
float: left; }

#row1-col2 {margin: 0 0 0 100px;
float:left; }

.element1 {display: inline;
text-align:center;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0 15px 0 8px; }

.element1 a:link, a:visited {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none; }

.element1 a:hover, a:active {
color: #f00;
border-bottom: 3px solid #f00;  }
```

```html
<div id="row1">
<div id="row1-col1"><img src="images/image.gif" width="100px"></div>
<div id="row1-col2">
<div class="element1"><a href="#3">HOME</a></div>
<div class="element1"><a href="#4">THEMES</a></div>
<div class="element1"><a href="#5">AUTHORS</a></div></div>
```

Inserting `<br>`s before the elements with class "element1" pushes those elements down, but as it does so it also pushes down the margin line under the entire parent, so the underlining of "HOME" etc. never actually meets the margin line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is set a height on the same element that you add `border-bottom` to:

```
#row1 {
  height: 18px; // Equal to the underline
}
```

Note that you may have to adjust the height based on the image (which doesn't load in my fiddle, as it's a relative link).

Also note that considering the black line is a `border-bottom` on a parent element of the red line, this will be displayed *in front*, as you current use `overflow: hidden`. You also need to update it to have `overflow: visible`.

```
#row1 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: visible;
  border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
  height: 18px;
}
```

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/0syuwdy3/).

If you want to move the links down without adjusting the image, please be aware that you need to add more `margin-top` to `#row1`, and a negative `margin-top` directly to the image. For an image of 100px height:

```
#row1 {
  margin-top: 100px; // The height of the image
}
#row1 img {
  margin-top: -90px;
}
```

I've created a secondary [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/gpbv3ve2/) here showcasing this.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is close! When I push the "element1" elements down, the red underlining remains and the div edge doesn't get pushed down, but the div edge disappears not just under the red underlining but also between the elements.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you're pushing the elements down. If you adjust `margin-top` on `#row1` it will push the elements down, with both lines staying in place correctly. Can you please let me know how you're shifting down the elements, or try shifting them down by adjusting `margin-top`? If you're talking about moving the links down **without** adjusting the image, please be aware that they're both a child of `row1`, so to fix that, you need to add a **negative** `margin-top` directly to the image :)

Comment: Here's a new fiddle showcasing what I mean, using a placeholder image -- https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/gpbv3ve2/ -- is this what you were looking for? :)

Comment: I was pushing them down by inserting `<br>`s before them, which I know is a very dirty way to go about it. Your latest fiddle does the job perfectly if I increase the height of row1 to 40px.

Comment: Awesome, so I take it the problem is solved then? I've updated the answer itself to briefly discuss the image offset, and also link to the new fiddle. Let me know if you still have any issues, otherwise don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

your

```
#row1-col2 {
    float: left;
}
```

to

```
#row1-col2 {
    float: right;
}
```

will fix the problem

Comment: The author doesn't have a `#row-col2`, nor will changing the correct ID to  `float: right` fix the problem.

Comment: sorry #row1-col2 instead of #row-col2

Comment: Thanks for this. I've now tested that, but when I put `<br>`s before the "element1" elements, the margin line moved down too and the underlining disappeared.